# How button works

Tags: html, css

How to show the text under the button when clicking it and when you click the button again the text will disappear i'm just helping my friend :D

thankyou for helping me again :D

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Hover </span></button>
```

Comment: Which text below the button? I don't understand the question... also, take a look at this when editing your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i want the some text to appear when clicking the button sorry

Comment: You'll have to edit your question and tell us precisely what you want to achieve. Now I understand what you want, but I don't know how you want to achieve this. Only CSS? Will you use JS? What steps have you tried to make it work? Take a look at the guide I sent and re-ask your question. Then I will remove my down vote.

Answer (score 0):

The only way, that comes to my mind is to use JavaScript.

The only thing you would have to code is to check the value of 'display' property on click. If it is 'none' set it to 'block' and vice versa: if it is 'block' set it to none.

That should be it:

```js
$(document).ready(

  function () {

    $(".button").click(
    function() {
      var display_v = $(".popup").css("display");
      var popup = $(".popup");

      if (display_v == "none"){
        popup.css({"display":"block"});
      } else if (display_v == "block"){
        popup.css({"display":"none"});
      }
    });
  }
);
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}

/* The message 'box' */
.popup {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Hover </span></button>

<div class="popup">
  <p>The messages go here</p>
</div>
```